# Count instances of inherited classes separately and transparently

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'd like to count the number of every derived types of `Chara` without having to recopy too much code (basically this has to be transparent in the derived class implementation)

What I want:

```cpp
Knight k1;
Knight k2;
Paladin p1;
Paladin p2;
k1.name() // Knight 1
k2.name() // Knight 2
p1.name() // Paladin 1
p2.name() // Paladin 2
```

Template countable class with static variable:

```cpp
template<typename t>
class Countable
{
protected:
    Countable() { ID = ++count; };

    static int count;

    int ID;
};

template<typename t>
int Countable<t>::count = 0;
```

What works:

```cpp
class Chara
{
public:
    virtual std::string name() const = 0;
};
class Knight : public Chara, public Countable<Knight>
{
    std::string name() {return "Knight" + std::to_string(ID);}
};
class Paladin : public Chara, public Countable<Paladin>
{
    std::string name() {return "Paladin" + std::to_string(ID);}
};
```

However I have to copy the templated inheritance and the get_ID() function.
What I'm asking is : is there a way to do it relative to the base class?

I tried this:

```cpp
Chara : public Countable<Chara>
{
public:
    std::string name() const { return class_name() + " " + std::to_string(ID); }
protected:
    virtual std::string class_name() const = 0;
};
Knight : public Chara
{
    std::string class_name() const { return "Knight"; }
};
Paladin : public Chara()
{
    std::string class_name() const { return "Paladin"; }
};
```

But i don't know how to template it automatically for each class, which mean it does this:

```cpp
Knight k1;
Knight k2;
Paladin p1;
Paladin p2;
k1.name() // Knight 1
k2.name() // Knight 2
p1.name() // Paladin 3
p2.name() // Paladin 4
```

Comment: [Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)?

Comment: This might work! I've never thought of it before it's indeed very curious. If it works I'll answer my own question. Thank you.

Comment: Since the goal appears to make Countable unobtrusive to the bulk of the codebase, I don't think it'll be possible.  There are strategies such as using virtual Countable, and passing a token (e.g., the `typeid` of the class to Countable's constructor as a `std::type_info const&`) in the concrete class's constructor — but that's a lot of instrumentation.  (A class is constructed like an onion, most-base-class first.  Hence `typeid(*this)` won't be fully formed in the Countable constructor... drat.)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude as stated by @Eljay this doesn't work as if forces all the occurences of the class `Chara` to be templated in the code base.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Someprogrammerdude's comment I figured it out using a intermediate `CountableChara` Class

```cpp
template<typename t>
class Countable
{
protected:
    Countable() { ID = ++count; };

    static int count;

    int ID;
};

template<typename t>
int Countable<t>::count = 0;

class Chara
{
public:
    virtual std::string name() const = 0;
};

template <typename t>
class CountableChara : public Chara, public Countable<t>
{
public:
    std::string name() const
    {
        return class_name() + " " + std::to_string(this->ID);
    }
};
class Knight : public CountableChara<Knight>
{
public:
    std::string class_name() const { return "Knight"; }
}
class Paladin : public CountableChara<Paladin>
{
public:
    std::string class_name() const { return "Paladin"; }
}
```

This makes the class Chara being non template and the classes that inherit CountableChara not having to do anything fancy for the count stuff.